# Origin of what seems to be a Front-Panel

Tags: minicomputers, identify-this-peripheral

Reorganizing my desk - more exact the piles below - I once again came across this mystery front-panel. I can't remember what it was from nor who owns the **`||/`** logo present on chips and board(*1).

[image]

**Front Side**

Of the switches all are toggle, except in the top row  the two left and rightmost are momentary. So while the ones in the top row are of different size (maybe according to function) and grouped, they still differ within the first group.

The lower row are 24 toggle switches and Lamps. Don't get confused by the missing 9th lamp (from the right). With 24 toggle switches in the bottom row, it may be either have been a 12 bit machine (12 bit address/12 bit data), or an 8 bit with 16 bit address.

[image]

**Back Side**

The top left writing is `CSL CONT` while the number on the top right is 11001481-D. The two metal braces at the metal frame are numbered `15000751`.Speaking of metal, the bolts and nuts used *seem* to be imperial, so it's either a US or UK product, as any other place would have used metric.

Each of the three IC, labelled `IO/7`, seem to encode the switches (maybe 12 bit wide,as 8 from below and 3-4 from above) and controlling 8 lamps. They all carry the same production number `91130072`.

I would assume their part number system being based on 8 digit numbers (*2), possibly structured, possibly with a 2+ digit type code (left justified) with the remaining counting parts.

[image]

There's also a paper sticker with what appears to be a serial number:

```
5122 271 03041
SERIAL 400580
```

---

*1 -I'm pretty sure I will feel like a real idiot as soon as someone points out that logo.

*2 - 8 being a nice length for such, often pointing to a /370ish system using BCD (4 byte key length).

Comment: No clue from the large ICs on the board?

Comment: @chthon Not really, beside them being really early ones. For sure no later standard devices. They seem to be made by (or for) the same company that made the PCB. Added detail pics.

Comment: 40 pin ceramic DIP packaging with gold lid - you can still get those today. I was wondering if the logo is more an /II, perhaps for AI. I can't find anything matching from Analog Devices, and searching for "AI" is hopeless at this point. No hits on the markings 91130072 i/o 7 5 in various combinations.

Comment: @JonCuster it's certainly not new. I own it already for quite some time. AnalogDeviced uses their triangle in square (Op-Amp) logo since at least 1965 and AD as chip prefix since at least 1971. Also, it seems hard to believe that the logo would be put on, in both cases (chip and PCB),  in a different orientation as writing.

Comment: I know it isn't new, and I would not expect white ceramic these days, but I've packaged parts that way in the not-too-distant past (they are good for vacuum packaging). I still find the keys intriguing, but can't find any pictures of similar things from old accelerators, fab equipment, or laser systems. Approximate date of acquisition? And I presume you can't find the panel that goes over it? Other markings, language, ...?

Comment: @JonCuster white ceramics are still the go to for low volume/special interest chips. Same goes for gold contacts. The device must be from the early70s. I wouldn't ask if I had a slightest idea where to search. Same goes for any other part. What's displayed is all I have and it really puzzles me since years.

Comment: The bottom row of switches seems to be grouped in 15 and 8. Could be a PDP-8 clone (I'm thinking with its 15-bit addressing). The eight switches might be the usual front-panel ones: Deposit, Load, Cont, single stepping, etc. etc. Does that sound plausible to you?

Comment: It would be useful information, if you can include it, to know which of these switches are momentary contact switches. And, if you are sure this circuit board even comes from a computer, and not from, say, an alarm system or something.

Comment: The back of the board is a bit blurry, but it appears that ||/ logo is also embossed at the bottom center of the board, correct?  And there is some number in the top right, but I can't make it out from the picture.

Comment: Also, I did find this exchange, but it unfortunately doesn't add any new information. http://forum.6502.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3183&view=next

Comment: @OmarandLorraine No, it's plain 24 switches and lamps on the bottom row - just one lamp is missing from its socket. And yes, chances are good that the upper part is the usual function switches. Of the top row, the two left most and two rightmost are momentary, all other are toggle. I'm pretty sure its from a computer.

Comment: @Geo... Yes, it's the same logo. that's why I would think it's from some larger company. Text on the back of the PCB (left) is CSL CONT, number (right) is 11001481-D.Two brackets on the metal frame carry a 15000751 stamp. Can't find any on the cast frame itself. The post you found is based on a posting I did15 years ago on Google+. Also I would think it's of US or UK origin as the bolts used seem to be imperial - clear indicator it's not a (continental) European product.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Four-Phase Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-Phase_Systems)

I worked with others who programmed Four-Phase computers. I really can't add more. I simply remembered the logo.

This image appears to show a similar, if not identical front panel.

[image: Four-Phase Computer]

([Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=5881449))

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you so much. This panel bugged me the better part of two decades. Now I need a detailed picture of the front screen to make it look like it should. Plus ofc, all I can get on that system. New Target acquired :))

Comment: Oh, and yes, as predicted, I feel totally dumb now. Of course I know the Four-Phase systems and their logo.

Comment: So the logo is not "||/" but rather "IV"?

Comment: @Theodore - A *stylized* Roman numeral "IV" with the "V" slanted and separated at the bottom thus providing a distinctive (and in my case, memorable) appearance.